# UIModalPresentationFormSheet With Square (0 Radius) Corners?

Tags: ios4, uimodalpresentationformsh

By default iPad modal form sheets get rounded corners. In a couple of Apple's apps, such as iTunes, the form sheets have perfectly square corners. Is there a relatively easy way to remove the corner radius that won't get me rejected from the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this inside the view you are showing:

```
//You will have to link to the QuartzCore library
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    //set border radius on initial load
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
     //for some reason the cornerRadius resets itself on orientation change
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Setting this at viewWillAppear, rather than viewDidLoad, ensures that the you never see the default beveled corners. Otherwise, this works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Coming here from 2016: This code did not work for me, but self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0; did. Give that a shot if the above code doesn't work for you.